# Does PostgreSQL REFERENCE always make a full copy of the value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

After searching endlessly, I couldn't even find an answer in the official documentation.

So we have these tables, with a `user_id TEXT` primary key. We want to reference this key, which is maybe 128 bytes. We don't want to copy that large string so many times, so we're considering a `bridge_id INT`.

This makes me wonder, because in other languages if you create a reference to a string, it will be an actual pointer to the string, not a full copy of the string. Does PostgreSQL, or SQL in general, store a reference or the full copy of the string value?

Comment: "Reference this key" as in "have a foreign key onto this column"? Well, in SQL there is no such thing as pointers, you need to put the same value in the foreign key column that is present in the primary key column. Possible workaround: if I remember correctly, you can reference on any unique column with a foreign key, so you might introduce this ```bridge_id``` to your original table and put a unique and not-nullable constraint on it and use it for your foreign keys

Comment: no they store the complete text, but add a new primary key and make the user_id unique.

Comment: See the [help], especially "[ask]" and on creating a [mcve]. See also the [tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking on the wrong abstraction level. A primary keys is not data that you reference (point to), it *is* the reference (or pointer) for the table row. Same as you store the address of an object, you store the primary key *value* in another table to reference a certain table row.

Your choice of a 128-character string as primary key is unfortunate, because it means that you have to copy those 128 characters to every table that has a foreign key constraint referencing your table.

Comment: That seems to be the default behavior with ASP.NET Identity, unfortunately. It's 36 characters, not 128, but it's hexadecimal (not even alphanumeric) `TEXT/VARCHAR` primary keys for everything. Seems MS wants to see those Azure DBs fill up fast?

Anyway, the consensus is that what you say is true. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You said 128 bytes in your question...

Comment: Yeah I know, it's the same concept anyway. Long string of X bytes.